# Under Windows is there a way for an admin to copy a limited account password from one machine to another?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, passwords, home-networking

I the admin of a home network with "home" version of Windows Vista and Windows 7. A Vista machine downstairs is connected to a printer. Now for other machines to access the printer, I understand that there must be a matching account (same username/password) on the "printer" machine, as home versions of windows can't remember login credentials.

My problem is that, although I can create an account on the "printer" machine for each user on the other machines, I can't match passwords, as, of course, I don't know them. Presently, I must involve each user to go and set the password on the "printer" machine. And if the user subsequently changes his/her password, there is a problem.

Is there a way for an admin to "copy" the unknown password for each user account and "paste" it onto the second machine?

Answer (score -1):

Yes:

> Start - run - cmd - compmgmt.msc /computer="computername"

Then, you can go in Users/Groups and add users where you need to.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the question.